# Avoid Jquery slide return the original state

Tags: jquery, html, asp-classic, slide

Im relatively new on asp, i have a panel that slide down (jquery) and show a couple of controls like text box and dropdownlist, these controls are disabled , when click on a botton to enable them, reloads the page and the panel that was in the bottom gets back to the original state so i want to avoid that , but i dont know how.

please helpme!!!

My code :

```
<html>

        <script src="/js/trirand/jquery.slide.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#mostrarocultar').click(function() {
                    $('#divmostoc').slideToggle(2500);
                });
            });
        </script>


    <body>           

       <div id="divmostoc" style="display:none" align="left" runat="server"  > 

               <br />  <font color="<%= ColorLogoutBack %>" size="3" style="font-weight:bold" face="Montserrat,verdana" >Domicilio/</font>   <asp:TextBox ID="tbDomicilio" runat="server" Text="Sur 67 A Num.107 Int.01" ReadOnly="True" ForeColor="DarkSlateGray"   BorderStyle="None" Font-Size="Small"  Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Montserrat,verdana"></asp:TextBox> <br/><br/>
                <font color="<%= ColorLogoutBack %>" size="3" style="font-weight:bold" face="Montserrat,verdana" >Estado Civil/ </font> &nbsp <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEstadoC" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList> <br/><br/>
                <font color="<%= ColorLogoutBack %>" size="3" style="font-weight:bold" face="Montserrat,verdana" >Escolaridad/</font> &nbsp <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEscolaridad" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList> <br/><br/>
                <font color="<%= ColorLogoutBack %>" size="3" style="font-weight:bold" face="Montserrat,verdana" >Teléfono(s)/</font> <br/><br/>
                <font color="<%= ColorLogoutBack %>" size="3" style="font-weight:bold" face="Montserrat,verdana" >Dependientes/</font><br/><br/>
                <font color="<%= ColorLogoutBack %>" size="3" style="font-weight:bold" face="Montserrat,verdana" >Beneficiarios Gastos Médicos Mayores/</font><br/><br/>

                <asp:Button   ID="btnEditar" align="right" runat="server" " Text="Editar" Width="57px" Height="17px" BorderWidth ="1px" CssClass="fondo_botones_azul" Font-Size="8pt" Font-Bold="true" CausesValidation="False" />

       </div>

             <input id="mostrarocultar" onclick="changeText()"   type="button" style="  background-color:#089dd5; width:100; height:15;  color  :White;border:0px solid;font-size:8pt ; float: left  ;  " value="Mas..." /> 

    </body>
    </html>


 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     function changeText() {
         var elem = document.getElementById('mostrarocultar')                 

         if (elem.value == 'More...') {
             elem.value = '...Less'
         }
         else  {
             elem.value = 'More...'
         }  
     }  

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion simply use [HTML5 LocalStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), it will store data locally within the user's browser. So every time you reload your page, just check the localStorage first, then decide the state. Here is example how to read and write to localStorange:

```
// Store
localStorage.lastname = "Smith";
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.lastname;
//Remove
localStorage.removeItem("lastname");
```